# Vector - using iterator vs index

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to C++,

I have two pieces of code:

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != inventoryvec.size(); i++)
{
    cout << inventoryvec[i].description << endl;
}
```

and

```
    for (std::vector<items>::iterator it = inventoryvec.begin(); it != inventoryvec.end(); ++it) 
    {
        cout << inventoryvec[it].description;
    }
```

The second code is not valid "Error no operator "[]" matches these operands" - why am I unabled to use "it" in the same way I use "i". It main purpose it to represent a value right?

Is this a limitation of using the iterator over indices or am I just doing something wrong.

Comment: I think there might be examples showing how to iterate over vectors out on the web somewhere.

Comment: Yes there is thanks, asking more specifically why it cannot be used in the same way as i

Comment: It's because you need to dereference `*it` ot get `it`-s value. As it is, `it` is an __iterator object__ and you can use `operator*` to get to the value it's holding.

Comment: Thank you very much - so to clarify  - "it" represents the value at the given index - which in this case is an object of type item, well the address until it is dereferenced by * or -> ?

Comment: Sorry, not operator*, because that's for multiplication, but you need to dereference it.

Comment: Essentially. Thinking of it like that helps clarify things. [Check this vid out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vO2AlrBf5rQ&index=6&list=PL5jc9xFGsL8G3y3ywuFSvOuNm3GjBwdkb) for info about iterators. The guy explains pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterators are just abstract pointers. 
An iterator points to a member. You dereference it with `*` (or you can use use `->`), advance it with `++`, and move it one item back (if that operation is implemented) with `--`.

In the case of vectors, there's virtually no abstraction. Vector iterators are (or can be) (with the exception of specializations) literally pointers to the members of the array that `std::vector` wraps.

Comment: Thank you that helps with my understanding

Answer (score 2):

To dereference a vector use the `*` operator.

Replace `inventoryvec[it]` with `(*it)`.

Of course, like usual, you can use `it->description` as shorthand for `(*it).description`.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `std::vector<items>::iterator` as a pointer of `items` type but more complicated. Thus, you use the dereference operator (aka *) to access the data to which it points. You can use `->` operator as well